# How can I filter two years ago from current date in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, npgsql

I want to take records from database which "creationDate" is no older than 2 years and 2 months back from now(UTC).

How can I filter by date keeping in mind that the value in "creationDate" is integer?

Thanks

Comment: `... "creationDate"  > = now() at time zone 'UTC' - '2 years 2 months'::interval;`? Is "creationDate" at `UTC`?

Comment: what do you mean by "creationDate" is long????

Comment: id your column is one of datetime types L: this should work nomatter what : `now() - interval '2 years 2 month' `

Comment: When your "long" is an integer, you have a problem: wrong data type. Change it to a proper date and the problem is gone.

Comment: @eshirvana I keep the date in miliseconds(13 digits), so this worked for me 
```where "creationDate" >= extract(epoch from now() - interval '2 years 2 month') * 1000 ```
thank you

Comment: Or alternate shorter form: `where to_timestamp("creationDate"/1000) >=  now() - interval '2 years 2 month' `.

Comment: You want _rows_ , from a _table_.